# error: 'Mystruct' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, gcc

I cannot sort a compile time error. I am compiling C project. My `main.c` file has an #include  where it can pick up the definition of a structure I am using for my project. The point is that each time that I am trying to compile my code I have the error

```
struct Mystruct* ps = (struct Mystruct* )malloc( sizeof(Mystruct) ); // I have this
// error at compile time

error: 'Mystruct' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

How it can be why the compiler is not able to read the structure definition?
The include folders are set correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like you need to either use `sizeof(struct Mystruct)` in your expression or use a `typedef struct Mystruct Mystruct` somewhere. In C, structs have their own namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I worked 9 years in C++ and now working in C is driving me crazy even for minimal things!